# Hibernate: Could not determine type for: > java.util.List

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am getting the following hibernate error, if anyone can help me resolve it, I would appreciate the help.

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:
>   java.util.List, at table: Lob, for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(approvers)]

There is a problem with the way I join the two tables:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity =     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = AutoApprovalApproverConfiguration.class, mappedBy = "lob", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
//@OrderBy("mandateLevelAmount")
private List<AutoApprovalApproverConfiguration> approvers;
```

More info:

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE public.lob
(
    lobid bigint NOT NULL,
    name character varying(150) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    description character varying(250) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    departmentid bigint,
    companyid bigint NOT NULL,
    datedisabled character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    disabled boolean,
    lastupdated timestamp without time zone,
    CONSTRAINT cc1178706309176 PRIMARY KEY (lobid),
    CONSTRAINT fk12b1f66ea598 FOREIGN KEY (companyid)
        REFERENCES public.merchants (merchant_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE public.autoapprovalapproverconfig
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    approverid bigint,
    linemanagerid bigint,
    lobid bigint,
    mandatelevelamount numeric(20,2),
    CONSTRAINT autoapprovalapproverconfig_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fkc33597b970049bf4 FOREIGN KEY (linemanagerid)
        REFERENCES public.person (personid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT fkc33597b99cc58a80 FOREIGN KEY (approverid)
        REFERENCES public.person (personid) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
```

Entities:

Lob.java

```
public class Lob implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "lob_sequence", sequenceName = "lob_ids")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "lob_sequence")
    private Integer lobid;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = AutoApprovalApproverConfiguration.class, mappedBy = "lobid", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    //@OrderBy("mandateLevelAmount")
    private List<AutoApprovalApproverConfiguration> approvers;
```

AutoApprovalApproverConfiguration.java

```
public class AutoApprovalApproverConfiguration implements Serializable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1604255007323958024L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(allocationSize = 1, name = "seq_autoapprovalapproverconfig_id", sequenceName = "seq_autoapprovalapproverconfig_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="seq_autoapprovalapproverconfig_id")
    private Long id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "lobid")
    private Lob lob;
    private BigDecimal mandateLevelAmount;
```

error:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:
>   java.util.List, at table: Lob, for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(approvers)]

I am using Java 7 and Hibernate 1.2.0.Final

Comment: Really hibernate 1.2.0? That must be older than 20 years!

Comment: Haha yes, I'm afraid so. This is an application that's been around long before I arrived.

Comment: It might be simply incompatible to Java 7. Did you try an older Java version? Do you have other similar entities which work fine? Then you can try to find the relevant difference.

Comment: It's an app that's been working for many years, so I don't want to change versions just to fix a small bug.

Comment: So the app was using Java 7 already before? Then try to find the differences comparing with similar entities which has similar onetomany/manytoone lists.